# how to convert default value of ngx-material-timepicker

Tags: angular

i want to update time using ngx-material-timepicker in html. so when i select the time it is in format 03:20 am and i want it in 03:20 AM

i converted the data in 12 hr format and but it is not working

TS code

```js
convert24To12HourFormat(time): string {
    let timeArray = time.split(":");
    let timeIn12HourFormat = "";
    if (parseInt(timeArray[0]) <= 12) {
      timeIn12HourFormat += time + " AM";
    }
    else {
      var newhh = (timeArray[0] - 12) + "";
      if (parseInt(newhh) < 10) {
        newhh = "0" + newhh;
      }
      timeIn12HourFormat = newhh + ":" + timeArray[1];
      timeIn12HourFormat += " PM";
    }
    return timeIn12HourFormat;
  }
```

HTML CODE

```html
<div>
    <div *ngIf="editable == true">
        <input [ngxTimepicker]="starttime" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="eventStartTime" name="eventStartTime"  placeholder={{eventStartTime}} (ngModelChange)="fieldsChanged();">
        <ngx-material-timepicker #starttime ></ngx-material-timepicker>
    </div>
    <b *ngIf="editable == false">{{eventStartTime}}</b>
</div>
```

expected output 03:20 AM
actual output 03:20 am

Comment: you should pass the `current selected time of the input` to the `value attribute of input` element. in your .ts file get the time. e.g `time = input.value` then pass the time variable to the `input value attribute`. e.g `value="time"` this will fix the problem. all the `attributes` and `methods` are defined here. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker#ngxtimepicker

Answer (score 0):

you can upper-case the value

`eventStartTime.toUpperCase()`

`'03:20 am'.toUpperCase() // '03:20 AM'`